# Call for an extension method of Enum

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, extension-methods

I am using ToStringEnum extension like:

```
public static string ToStringEnum(this YearOfSchooling value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
    }
}

public static string ToStringEnum(this Grade value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
    }
}
```

and so forth every enum.

Now I want to create generic TML Extension to read this enum WHERE T is enum.

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
{
    return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof (T), value, true);
}

public static MvcHtmlString DisplayEnumRowWithDisplayName<TModel, TValue, T>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) where T : struct, IEnumConverter
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var model = metaData.Model;
    var displayName = metaData.DisplayName;

    string parsedValue = string.Empty;
    if (model != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ToString()))
        {
            var parsedEnum = EnumUtils.ParseEnum<T>(model.ToString());
            var type = typeof(T);
            parsedValue = type.GetMethod("ToStringEnum", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        }
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(
        "<div class=\"control-group\"><label class=\"control-label\">{0}</label><div class=\"controls\"><span class=\"input-xlarge uneditable-input\">{1}</span></div></div>"
        .FormatWith(displayName, parsedValue));
}
```

But I don't klnow how to invoke ToStringEnum method. I tried with:

```
parsedValue = type.GetMethod("ToStringEnum", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

but not working and I am out of ideas.

Comment: Extension methods are sugar coating from the compiler.. they are not directly associated with class for which extension method is defined.. hence refection on the type will not provide you access to extension method in any way.. you have to consider alternatives.. which would depend on your real need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up the extension method itself:

```
    private static void TestEnumExtension<T>(T enm)
    {
            Type[] types = {enm.GetType()};
            MethodInfo method = typeof(Extension).GetMethod("ToStringEnum", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, types, null);
            Console.WriteLine(method.Invoke(null, new object[] {enm}));
    }
```

In this case, Extension is the extension class. 'enm' is the generic enumeration instance.

Answer (score 0):

The extension method isn't attached to the type T, it's attached to the type Class that declare ToStringEnum extension method

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(extension method class name).GetMethod("ToStringEnum", new[] { typeof(T) });

var result = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { parsedEnum });
```